Problem with dependency injection with TSyringe TypeORM Express
I am a student just starting on personal projects.
I am currently doing web-backend, and making a server using Express, TypeScript, MySQL, with typeorm and tsyringe libraries.
I am experiencing a bug that I can't fix for hours currently :(
Error resolving UserController: Error: Cannot inject the dependency "userService" at position #0 of "UserController" constructor. Reason:
    Cannot inject the dependency at position #0 of "UserService" constructor. Reason:
        Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "UserRepository"

So from the error, I am thinking that userService was not registered properly at the right point.
I've dumbed down app.ts, server.ts for debugging purposes.
I think I am doing it in the correct order (Initializing Database (ormconfig.ts) at my entry point, which as all of the dependency registration) but it keeps on telling me that the UserRepository dependency token is unregistered.
My code is as follows:
server.ts (entry point):
import app from './app';
import userRouter from './routes/user.router';
import { initializeDatabase } from './config/ormconfig';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

initializeDatabase().then(() => {
    app.use('/api/user', userRouter);

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello World');
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error starting the server:', error);
});

app.ts:
import 'reflect-metadata';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

export default app;


user.router.ts:
import { Router } from 'express';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { UserController } from '../controllers/user.controller';

const router = Router();
try {
    const userController = container.resolve(UserController);
    console.log('usercontroller successfully resolved', userController);

    router.post('/register', userController.createUser.bind(userController));
    router.post('/login', userController.loginUser.bind(userController));
    router.get('/:user_key', userController.getUserByKey.bind(userController));
    router.get('/', userController.getAllUsers.bind(userController));
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error resolving UserController:', error);
}
export default router;

user.controller.ts:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { injectable, inject } from 'tsyringe';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@injectable()
export class UserController {
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }
// methods 

user.service.ts:
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Address } from '../entities/address.entity';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { injectable, inject } from 'tsyringe';

@injectable()
export class AddressService {
    constructor(
        @inject('UserService') private userService: UserService,
        @inject('AddressRepository') private addressRepository: Repository<Address>
    ) { }
// methods

ormconfig.ts
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { container } from 'tsyringe';
import { REPOSITORY_TOKENS } from './constants';

import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';

import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });

const { DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD } = process.env;

if (!DB_DATABASE || !DB_USER || !DB_HOST || !DB_PASSWORD) {
    throw new Error('Missing database configuration environment variables.');
}

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    username: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DB_DATABASE,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: false,
    entities: [User, Address, Routine, Item, SkinAttribute, ItemOrder, OrderDetail, Review],
});


export const initializeDatabase = async () => {
    try {
        await AppDataSource.initialize();
        console.log('Database connection established successfully');

        const repositories = [
            { name: 'UserRepository', entity: User },
            // other entities
        ];

        for (const repo of repositories) {
            container.register(repo.name, { useValue: AppDataSource.getRepository(repo.entity) });
        }

        container.register(UserService, { useClass: UserService });
        // other services

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing database:', error);
    }
}

If anyone could help me out and give me some tips or ideas, that would be great!
To remove any typos in the names of the repositories, i've made a separate constants.ts file to fill in, for no luck.
Most of my changes I've already applied in the code above, but got the same error.
